# Fix Nav rolling when use carousel - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootrap nav-fix top, In mobile mode the fixed navigation bar scrolls using the carousel, only in mobile mode this happens

i try fix with css change but no sucess

i dont know to fix that, thanks for help

[Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/ennoorec/)

```
         <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>

            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#fotos">Fotos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contato</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>


    <!-- Galeria Section -->
    <section id="fotos" class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Galeria de Fotos</h2>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="carousel slide article-slide" id="myCarousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner cont-slider">

                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x440/cccccc/ffffff">
                            </div>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </section>
   <script>$('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use the following media queries its work fine for your issue.

@media (max-width:767px) { .navbar-static-top { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; margin: 0; } }

Comment: did not work look that exemple
http://www.goonoutdoor.com.br/lavrasnovastrailrace/index-teste.html